# Mostrar formulario dependiendo de valor en variable SESSION en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de mostrar un formulario dependiendo de un valor en la variable session, al momento de iniciar sesion mando a llamar varios datos y los almaceno en la variable session, uno de estos es operario, pero quiero que si la variable tiene la palabra operario en el valor ope, que este muestre un formulario, y si no la tiene que muestre otro formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que tengo que hacerlo con una condicion if pero el problema es que no encuentro la manera de realizarlo con este, espero alguien me pueda ayudar

este es el codigo con el que hago el login

```
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT usuarios.idUsuario, usuarios.email, usuarios.ope, usuarios.password, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.apellidos, usuarios.imagen, perfusu.genero, perfusu.edad, perfusu.ciudad, perfusu.estado, perfusu.edoCivil, perfusu.telCasa, perfusu.telCel, perfusu.domicilio, perfusu.datsFamilia, perfusu.viviendo, perfusu.actInteres, perfusu.profesion, perfusu.universidad, perfusu.profesion2, perfusu.profesion3, perfusu.diplomados, perfusu.talleres, perfusu.seminarios, perfusu.maestrias, perfusu.doctorados, perfusu.areaDesempenar, perfusu.sueldoDeseado, perfusu.empleo, perfusu.jefe, perfusu.puestoDesempenar, perfusu.salario, perfusu.periodo, perfusu.idioma, perfusu.nivel, perfusu.idioma2, perfusu.nivel2, perfusu.extra, perfusu.cv
FROM perfusu INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.idUsuario WHERE usuarios.email = :email AND usuarios.password = :password'
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password,
    ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado;
        header('Location: ' . RUTA . '/perfil.php');
    } else {
        $errores .= '<li>Datos Incorrectos</li>';
    }
}

require 'views/login.php';
```

toda la consulta se guarda en el session pero no se como seleccionar la variable ope,

> si ope es igual a operario mostrar formulario, sino mostrar otro.

Comment: publica el código amigo así se podría ayudar.

Comment: @JaimeMateus edite mi pregunta, espero eso te pueda servir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bien amigo podrías hacer lo siguiente :

```
$session_parts = explode("-", $_SESSION['usuario']);
```

**explico de manera breve :**
lo que hace explode() es separar el array que trae tu session lo cual podrías usarla de la manera

```
`$session_parts[0]`
```

para el primero de tu array y
`$session_parts[1]`
para el segundo de tu array y así validar tus dos parámetros que necesitas en el if() y así mostrar tu formulario.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, entendi a la perfeccion

Comment: recuerda amigo primero armar o bueno crear el array separado por un - de lo que arrojé el $resultado = $statement->fetch();

Comment: lo hice ya con la sesion abierta de la siguiente manera y me arroja este error `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez usuario\perfil.php on line 3`  `$session_parts = explode("-", $_SESSION['usuario']);`